# Cache implementation in Rust

Tags: rust

I've started learning Rust recently using the Rust book.

In one of the chapters, the authors encourage the reader to experiment with closures, and try to create a [generic cache implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html#limitations-of-the-cacher-implementation).

I've managed to get it working as below. However, it irks me that I need to add Clone trait on the input argument in the get() method. I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this?

Any other comments are also welcome (apart from the main() method which is a sample driver).

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::clone::Clone;

struct Cache<T, U, W>
    where T: Fn(U) -> W,
          U: Eq + Hash + Clone {
    calculator: T,
    values: HashMap<U, W>,
}

impl<T, U, W> Cache<T, U, W>
    where T: Fn(U) -> W,
          U: Eq + Hash + Clone {
    fn new(calculator: T) -> Cache<T, U, W> {
        Cache {
            calculator,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    /*
     * The ugliest part in this function is the constraint that we have to clone the input.
     * HashMap::entry() moves the key, which renders it unusable for subsequent calculations.
     * So we can either
     * - always perform the expensive computation
     * (OR)
     * - clone the input so that it can be re-used later
     *   
     * Another problem is that defining a closure in or_insert_with borrows the Cache::calculator, and that creates a problem
     * when we attempt to borrow it again by invoking self.calculator. This is why the following line won't work:
     * self.values.entry(input.clone()).or_insert_with(|| { (self.calculator)(input) })
     */  
    fn get(&mut self, input: U) -> &W {
        let calc = &self.calculator;
        self.values.entry(input.clone()).or_insert_with(|| { (calc)(input) })
    }   
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let mut c = Cache::new(|x: &str| {
        println!("performing an expensive calculation with input: {}", x);
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        format!("Original input: {}", x)
    });

    let x = c.get("10");
    println!("x: {}, cacher after getting {}", x, 10);

    let x = c.get("10");
    println!("x: {}, cacher after getting {}", x, 10);

    let x = c.get("20");
    println!("x: {}, cacher after getting {}", x, 20);

    let x = c.get("10");
    println!("x: {}, cacher after getting {}", x, 10);

    let x = c.get("10");
    println!("x: {}, cacher after getting {}", x, 10);

    let x = c.get("20");
    println!("x: {}, cacher after getting {}", x, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to have the `where` clause on your struct. General, rust coders prefer to only restrict the `impl` blocks and not the structs.

You can avoid Clone, by unpacking the Entry enum, like so:

```
fn get(&mut self, input: U) -> &W {
    use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;
    match self.values.entry(input) {
        Entry::Occupied(entry) => entry.into_mut(),
        Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
            let value = (self.calculator)(entry.key());
            entry.insert(value)
        }
    }
}
```

This is, in fact, close to how `or_insert_with` is implemented.

Note that this calls the function with `&U` not `U`. Your calculator cannot take ownership of the key if you also plan to put into the hashmap. This is awkward for your code because it is using &str as the keys. Hence the type passed to the calculator is &&str. We can resolve this by using the borrow trait. The Borrow traits knows that it can convert &&str to &str, so we could implement it as follows.

```
// Leave the struct unconstrained
struct Cache<T, U, W> {
    calculator: T,
    values: HashMap<U, W>,
}

// The impl block only constrains for Eq + Hash of the keys.
impl<T, U, W> Cache<T, U, W>
    where 
          U: Eq + Hash
         {

    fn new(calculator: T) -> Cache<T, U, W> {
        Cache {
            calculator,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    // We take a new type parameter, Y.
    // The calculation function takes &Y as a parameter
    // It does not need to be sized because we only use references to it.  
    fn get<Y:?Sized>(&mut self, input: U) -> &W 
        where 
             // Our calculator must take a reference to Y.
             T: Fn(&Y) -> W,
             // The borrow trait will let us convert a &U to a &Y
             U: std::borrow::Borrow<Y> {
        use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;
        match self.values.entry(input) {
            Entry::Occupied(entry) => entry.into_mut(),
            Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
                let value = (self.calculator)(entry.key().borrow());
                entry.insert(value)
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do we need the Borrow trait though? It appears the program works even if we constrain the T: Fn(&U) -> W, and just pass in entry.key() as a reference to self.calculator? I'm trying to understand if introducing the Borrow trait is somehow better?

Comment: @skittish, if you do that, you'll find that closure passed to `Cache::new` in your main function has to take a `&&str` parameter rather than the more natural `&str`. `Borrow` just gives the trait a bit more flexibility in what parameter it takes.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I think I misunderstood your comment in the answer about the Borrow trait. Thank you for the answer and the clarification.